# Rendering html text from model inside view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application, I have a view in which the content for the view will have to be rendered in html format. html string will be obtained form the model in the view. How can i rener the html mark up as such in view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "rendered in html format"? Are you meaning that you have HTML in your model and you want to insert it into the page, or that you have HTML in your model and want to display it to the user as HTML (like code view). Or something else?

Comment: You need to use some HTML rendering engine, obviously. You an embed IE viewer or you can look for some third-party HTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read through: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs to see an example of the ASPX view engine rendering HTML.

You shouldn't be building HTML in the model (or in the controller and putting it into the model).

**Update**: as Jamie Dixon has mentioned, there are situations in which business properties of the model will contain HTML.

Generally, speaking:
The model should contain properties and business logic.
The views will render the HTML that you need.
The controller calls the business logic needed and passes the model to the correct view.

If, in the view, you wish to write out a heading based on a property called Title on the Model, you can use this:

```
<h1><%: Model.Title %></h1>
```

or if you are storing a HTML string in a property called StoredHtml:

```
<div>
    <%= Model.StoredHtml%>
</div>
```

Note that `<%=` has been used rather than `<%:`, as `<%:` will encode HTML for security reasons (like `<script>` tags being saved).

Comment: I guess sometimes it is a requirement to store HTML in the database, especially in the case of a CMS etc. In that case it makes perfect sense that the model would contain a string of HTML.

Comment: No problem. Also, you've written <% Model.StoredHtml %>.... Did you mean <%= or did I miss that you can ommit the equels sign?

Comment: Thanks Jamie, that's my bad, I've been using RAZOR for ages so forgot about the differences between `<%`, `<%=` and `<%:`. As I understand it, you can omit the `=` if you're not rendering anything.